# How do I create a list of objects from a List(Of String) using LINQ in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of string in VB.Net which I would like to convert to 
a list of a (class) objects.

How would I do that using LINQ?

**Consider the following:**

```
Public Class FooClass
  Public Property Property1 As String

  Public Property Property2 as Boolean

  Public Sub New( prop1 as String, prop2 as Boolean)
     Property1 = prop1
     Property2 = prop2
  End Sub

End Class

Dim fooList as List(Of String)

Dim objectList as List(Of FooClass)
```

I would like to create a list of FooClass based on the contents of fooList.

I know there is a way to do this.
I'm not clear how to do this in VB.Net.

Thanks,
John

Comment: If you are not clear about how to do this, then that implies you have some knowledge on how to do it. Can you tell us what that is?

Comment: And what does `fooList` look like?

Comment: Your question still not clear for little bit, I think you want to use `For Each` loop with `fooList` and assign its content to `objectList`, won't you?

Comment: In general, you would do this: `objectList = fooList.Select(Function(s) ConvertStringToFooClass(s)).ToList()`. You haven't explained what each `String` contains and how that relates to a `FooClass` object so we can't tell you how that conversion would be done, but that's how to convert a `List` of one type to a `List` of another.

Comment: OK, figured it out. objectList  = (from item in fooList Select new FooClass(item, false)).ToList()

Comment: For the record, that is just the query syntax equivalent of the function syntax I provided. You can use whichever you like but, in a case like this, I find function syntax more natural: `objectList = fooList.Select(Function(s) New FooClass(s, False)).ToList()`.